# Show category description in top menu Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, topmenu, category-description

i'm trying to show the categories in the top menu with the corresponding category description but can't find any function for that.

With the object manager i can get the id, name etc. but not the description.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

// get current store’s categories
$categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
$categories = $categoryHelper->getStoreCategories();

foreach ($categories as $category) {
echo $category->getId() . '<br />';
echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
print_r($category->getData());. '<br />';

}
```

Any idea how i can get each category description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');

$categories = $categoryFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setStore($storeManager->getStore()->getId());

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    var_dump($category->getId());
    var_dump($category->getName());
    var_dump($category->getDescription());
}
```

**Info :**  I gave you this solution to guide you for getting what you need but, **using the object manager** is not a **recommended** way, use a block instead, you create some function `getCategoryDescription()` for exemple, then you get it in your phtml like this : `$block->getCategoryDescription()`.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I did it how you said and got rid of the object manager and put it instead in a custom block in a separate module.

Comment: Good job :) you're welcome !